# Predict cache line length using time measure

Tags: caching, assembly, size, line

Hi it's my first post here so Hi everyone.

I have problem with predict cache line size in GNU AS. I wrote program in C which calls a function written in assembly.

here is this function

```
.section .text
.section .data

.global time

time:
pushl %ebp
xor %edx, %edx
xor %eax, %eax
CPUID
RDTSC
popl %ebp   
ret
```

It measure CPU cycles

C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int size = 256;

void main(){

unsigned long long cykl, cykl1, cykl2;

unsigned char matrix[size];

char bla;

int i,j,k;

    for(i=0 ; i<size; i++)
        {
        cykl1 = time();
        bla = matrix[i];
        cykl2 = time();
        cykl = cykl2 - cykl1;

        printf("i=%d: %lld \n",i, cykl);
        }       
}
```

I ran this program, but I can't see any time difference. As I know my cache line lenght is 64 bytes.

Time should rise every time I load next 64bytes of array, am I right?

I will be gratefull for any advice why it can't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 problems.

First, what your program call might not be your assembly routine, but time(2) system call which returns the current time in seonds.
The assembly routine name should be prefixed with an underscore, i.e., _time, in your *.s file.

You can also declare the routine with `__asm__` keyword.  See:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Asm-Labels.html

Second, the memory access might be eliminated (or reordered) by GCC optimizer.
You should check the assembly code generated from your C code.

Third, `RDTSC` is not serialized.
In other words, the CPU might reorder an access to memory and an `RDTSC` insturction, or they are executed in parallel.
You should insert some instructions to prevent the reordering.

See the description of `RDTSC` in "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architecture Software Developer's Manual Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, M-Z":
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I checked which function is calling in gdb debugger, so program calls my function. I change also name of function, but it isn't help. 

I'm not sure what I have to check with this GCC optimizer.
Here is disassembly code
http://www.nopaste.pl/1kyr

About serializing `RDTSC` I think `CPUID` do it, am I right?

Comment: You missed a function declaration, i.e., `unsigned long long my_time()`.  Because of that, the function is declared as if `int my_time()` implicitly.  And you're right about serialization.  (What you should check was the order of first `my_time()`, access to the array, and second `my_time()` in the generated code.  It was okay.)